Wheel collider for skateboard falls through the floor in Unity?
Problem: Why are the wheel colliders not colliding with the floor?
Here's a video that shows how the skateboard just falls through the ground:
https://imgur.com/a/Vx7QraF
I have this kind of hierachy:

GameObject "Skateboard" with Rigidbody

4 wheel collider gameobjects with Wheel Collider components
skateboard mesh

4 wheel meshes
board mesh WITH box collider





Here are the settings for each wheel collider:

The wheels are pointing down and rotation is set to (0,0,0):

I've played with multiple different configurations, and I can't figure out why it is happening.

For something as small as a skateboard, I normally wouldn't try to model physics behaviour of each wheel. If you're making a skateboarding game, a custom character controller will likely yield better game feel more easily, and you can adjust the wheels as a purely visual flourish for the times when they're visible.

@DMGregory it's a fingerboarding game, so the board is actually bigger than normal to the player

You might want to scale everything up then, so 1.0 is more like 1 cm rather than 1 m. The physics engine is tuned for objects on the order of tenths to tens of units, so giving it extremely small or extremely large objects can lead to less stable/consistent behaviour. These tiny wheels at 0.0029 radius might be slipping below a minimum contact offset, causing or worsening the tunneling you're observing.
